# Regex - Select all numbers without commas

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-replace

I have been trying to capture only the numbers in this sentence so that it stays as follows:

Before:

```
 - 602,135 results
```

After:

```
602135
```

I was testing the following: `#\d+#`
But just select me `602`

PS: I had already consulted in other posts but they could not solve my problem.

Comment: It is not duplicate, I saw these post and I can not get a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **preg_replace**

**Try this**

```
$str = '- 602,135 results';
echo $result = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);
```

**Output -** 602135

You can also use to get same output:-

```
$result = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

`\D+` will do or equivalent to this is `[^0-9]`

will return digits only.

See it here: https://regex101.com/r/8CTgIm/1

[PHP] Use it like:

```
$re = '/\D+/';
$str = '- 602,135 results  ';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str); //602135

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regex for this.
Not sure you actually gain something on not using regex here but here is one alternative method.

```
$str = " - 602,135 results  ";

Echo str_replace("-", "", filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

It uses filter_var to remove anything that is not number and that leaves `-602135`.
Then I use str_replace to remove the negative sign.

https://3v4l.org/iAVOB#output